# Get the info.plist in packaging

Tags: ios, plist, target, build-settings

I added a custom-info.plist to the packaging section under Build settings for a new target.

When I run this target it still grabs `[AppName]-info.plist`. For this custom plist I copied `[AppName]-info.plist` contents into this custom plist file.

Update:

I created 2 Targets Dev and Staging
I created 2 .xcconfig files 
ENV = "Dev" - Dev.xcconfig
ENV = "Staging" - Staging.xcconfig

Then in my targets for debug I set the DevTarget to Dev.xcconfig and the StagingTarget to Staging.xcconfig

Im my plist file I added the line EnvironmentList = ${ENV}

Dev seems to work, but when I change it to my StagingTarget is its says Dev

Comment: It can't be possible as default one will always load. What's the purpose in loading the custom plist? anything specific to UI?

Comment: Yeah I have a plist with definitions for server locations, settings, etc based on dev, staging, test, preprod, and prod environments. I was hoping to specify another plist in my target. So I did that, I just don't know how to find out the name specified in packaging.

Comment: I already did what Abizem showed on the picture with my custom plist file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use a different plist file you can set it from your build settings:

[image]

Comment: Ok, so I did that already. How do I get that name at runtime that I used so can I open the plist file?